# Building Led light which work on 230V supply

Tags: led, light

I have a couple of 9W LED bulbs(1) at home with blown drivers. I got some replacement boards(3) with driver circuit and LEDs on the board itself. Now that the old LEDs(2) along with the aluminum PCBs are no longer required, I want to make a high power LED lamp which works on 230V AC. The LEDs are connected in series. With a working voltage of 3V each, I may require around ~76 LEDs (please correct me if I am wrong).

- Will a simple bridge rectifier and a filter capacitor do the job to light these LEDs?
- If yes, which values would you suggest for diodes and capacitor?

Another problem I may face is voltage fluctuation(not frequent) which may range from 200V to 250V. Am I wrong if I assume that this voltage fluctuation is not strong enough to damage the LEDs?

Any advice highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, just a rectifier and capacitor isn't enough.  You need something that will set the correct current through the diodes, or else they are liable to burn out.  That's especially the case if you suffer from voltage fluctuations.

The best solution is to use a proper LED driver.

The cheap alternative is a suitably high voltage capacitor to produce a "capacitive dropper".  If using a capacitive dropper, assume that any part of the circuit may be live and take appropriate precautions.